# Error SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, servidor, cpanel

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Laravel. Hice la implementación en un servidor compartido, pero aparece el mensaje de error `SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Acceso denegado para el usuario 'root' @ 'localhost (usando la contraseña: NO)`

El proyecto en Local me funciona correctamente, pero en el servidor está limitado solo al error. *Configuré las variables de entorno en mi archivo .env* por los datos correspondientes.

Creo que el servidor probablemente no lea el archivo **.env** y es por eso que surge el problema. ¿Alguien sabe a qué se puede deber?

**Repito:** Cambié los datos que tenía en local por mis datos de producción.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Te aseguraste de cambiar correctamente los datos (usuario, contraseña y nombre de la base de datos) en tu environment ? Por favor coloca esa configuración en tu pregunta

Comment: Sí señor. Cambié todos mis datos por los respectivos datos de mi base de datos, contraseña y usuario con todos los privilegios. Ya he subido archivos en Laravel pero sin bases de datos. Ahora el problema está en este proyecto. No me deja conectarme. No entiendo qué sucede realmente.

Answer (score 0):

Si el servidor no lee los datos del archivo **.env** deberas cambiar los datos necesarios en el archivo **config/database.php**

Imagino que estas usando mysql, entonces configura la variables que tu proveedor del servicio de hosting te ha dado:

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'RUTA_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'NOMBRE_BASE_DE_DATOS'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'USUARIO_BASE_DE_DATOS'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'CONTRASEÑA_USUARIO_BASE_DE_DATOS'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo intenté y aún así no me lee el archivo. Tuve que volver a hacer mi proyecto para ver si funcionaba y ahora sí me lee el archivo .env